# Is there a way to use CSS modules without adding .module. extension in NextJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, css-modules

I am trying to configure a NextJS project. I want to use CSS modules. However, I don't want to add `*.module.*` extension to file names and thus adding it to import paths, since it seems to me as excessive.

I found in [css modules documentation](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) that they didn't use `module` extension.

I tried to customize webpack configuration with loaders within next.config. Without any luck.

So, I am wondering if there is any way to be able to use just `someName.css` in NextJS. Then I could import it to my component just like this: `import style from './someName.css'`

Comment: No, there is no way to have scoped classnames without the .module extension in react. You can just import your css like `import './someName.css'`, but then you'd have to watch for collisions yourself. Or use another framework like vue or svelte which achieve that by having a scoped script tag inside the component file.